# Running multiple jobs in SageMaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I was wondering if it is possible to run large number of "jobs" (or "pipeline" or whatever is the right way) to execute some modelling tasks in parallel.

So what I planned to do is to do a ETL process and EDA done and after that when the data is ready, I would like to fire 2000 modelling jobs. We have 2000 products and each job can start with a data (SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE PROD_ID='xxxxxxxxx') and my idea is to run these training jobs in parallel (there is no dependency between them - so it makes sense to me).

First of all - 1) Can it be done in AWS SageMaker? 2) What would be the right approach? 3) Any special considerations I need to be aware of?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

it's possible to run this on SageMaker, with [SageMaker pipelines](https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sagemaker-pipelines/index.html) that will orchestrate a SageMaker [Processing job](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/processing-job.html), followed by a Training job. You can define the PROD_ID as a String parameter to the SageMaker Pipeline, then run multiple pipelines executions concurrently ([default soft limit is 200 concurrent executions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sagemaker.html)).
As you have a very high numbers of jobs (2K) which you want to run in parallel, and perhaps optimize compute usage, you might also want to look at  [AWS Batch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/what-is-batch.html), which allows you to queue up tasks, for a fleet of instances that starts containers to perform these jobs. AWS Batch also support Spot instances which could reduce your instance cost by 70%-90%. Another advantage of AWS Batch is that jobs reuse the same running instance (only container stop/start), while in SageMaker there's a ~2 minute overhead to start the instance per job. Additionally, AWS Batch also takes care of retries and allowing you to chain all 2,000 jobs together and run a "finisher" job when all jobs have completed.

**Limits increase -** For any service, you'll need to increase your service quota limits. It can be done from the console "Quotas" for most services, or by contacting AWS support. Some services has hard limits.

Comment: Thank you. As I indicated I am planning on running ETL job and then training jobs - so of course I am talking about ML modelling. 

So, my idea was that we create the ML model training and building pipeline in SageMaker. But as I mentioned, I need to do this for many products and they can run independently, so naturally I am looking for how to run these in parallel.

Comment: Got you. Adjusted answer accordingly.